# How to install puppet devel version from yum?

Tags: linux, centos, yum, puppet, rpm

In `/etc/yum.repos.d/puppet.repo` have I put

```
[puppetlabs]
name=Puppet Labs Packages
baseurl=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/$releasever/devel/$basearch/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs
```

and when I do

```
yum info puppet-server
```

it doesn't mention `puppet-server-3.0.0-0.1rc3` as being an option despite it is in the repository `http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6/devel/x86_64/`

What am I doing wrong?

Using CentOS 6.3 64bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rpm -Uvh http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6/devel/x86_64/puppetlabs-release-devel-6-1.noarch.rpm
```

No idea, why this works, but it does.

All it contains are

```
[root@puppet ~]# rpm -ql puppetlabs-release-devel-6-1
/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs-devel
/etc/yum.repos.d/puppetlabs-devel.repo

[root@puppet ~]# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/puppetlabs-devel.repo
[puppetlabs-devel]
name=Puppet Labs Devel 6 - $basearch
baseurl=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6/devel/$basearch
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-puppetlabs-devel
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
```

Comment: It adds the puppetlabs-devel repo to yum.  Once it's there, you can manage packages from the puppet dev channel within your standard yum setup.

Comment: The only difference I can see is the `baseurl` which should resolve to the same?

Comment: Hmm, good point.